# JFugue '+' not getting parsed? Chords not sounding

Tags: jfugue

Looks like in version 4.1x , 4.02 (these are the only ones i've tried) the harmony '+' is not working. When I execute:
 Player p = new Player();
  p.play ("C5maj");

I hear all three notes

but when I execute
 p.play("C+G+E");
I only hear the E note. The same goes for any 'chord' string as this. Seems only the last note is being played. Im running on linux.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

I figured out that when playing notes in parallel, the default duration mechanism isnt working. So playing C+G+E just gives you E. But if i play "Ch+Gh+Eh"..then I get the sounds from all the notes.

Comment: I believe this was a bug that has been fixed in later versions of JFugue.